# Does classical physics predict the effects of shining a laser at a hair?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

The discussion on [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=178383) webpage mentions that shining a laser beam at a hair produces an effect like that of the double-slit experiment.  Does classical physics predict the effect you observe when you do this (since light is a wave)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fringe pattern of a double slit is entirely classical - it even works with ocean waves.

[image: https://www.meted.ucar.edu/]

Why it still works with only one photon, and why it doesn't work if you look at the photon is quantum.

Comment: Even the idea of there being such a thing as a photon is quantum too.

Comment: @compman: Quantum ideas? :P